# How to check session storage for entries using selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, session, selenium-webdriver

I wish to check that a value is present in my session storage before proceeding with my test. However when I execute my script it comes back as undefined. Have tried the following:

```
let storage = await this.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionUser")')
console.log(storage)
```

and also this:

```
let storage = await this.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.length');
console.log(storage)
```

However both return undefined even though if I stop my test and manually check via the dev tools there is a key pair value present.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Which language binding you are using with Selenium ?

Comment: Hi Ishtita - We're using javascript, specifically the framework Cucucmberjs.